# Check list box to update grid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Here is my issue: 
I have a checklist box that is populated with students. When a student is selected by checking the check box I want it to show up in a data grid. Also if the student is un-checked he should be removed from the data grid.

I am able to bind my collection to a checklist box but when a student is checked it wont fire a property changed event I assume because the property changed is a child of the collection it is bound to. So I added property changed to the collection as well.

Below is some of the code I have been playing around with.

Where it is bound to:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectedStudent> ActiveStudents
{
    get { return _activeStudents; }
    set
    {
        _activeStudents = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("ActiveStudents");
        RaisePropertyChanged("GridDisplay");
    }
}

public IEnumerable<SelectedStudent> GridDisplay
{
    get
    {
        var aa = _activeStudents.Where(a => a.Select == true);
        return aa;
    }
    set
    {
        _activeStudents = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("GridDisplay");
    }
}
```

The selectedstudent class:

```
#region Fields

        private int _studentId;
        private string _firstName;
        private string _lastName;
        private bool _printCertificate;
        private bool _select;
        private int _testDateId;
        private string _rank;

        #endregion

public int StudentId
{
    get { return _studentId; }
    set
    {
        _studentId = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("StudentId");
    }
}

public string FirstName
{
    get { return _firstName; }
    set
    {
        _firstName = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("FirstName");
    }
}
public string LastName
{
    get { return _lastName; }
    set
    {
        _lastName = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("LastName");
    }
}

public string Student
{
    get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName); }
}

public bool PrintCertificate
{
    get { return _printCertificate; }
    set
    {
        _printCertificate = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("PrintCertificate");
    }
}
public bool Select
{
    get { return _select; }
    set
    {
        _select = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Select");
    }
}
public int TestDateId
{
    get { return _testDateId; }
    set
    {
        _testDateId = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("TestDateId");
    }
}
public string Rank
{
    get { return _rank; }
    set
    {
        _rank = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Rank");
    }
}

#region INotifyPropertyChanged

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
            }
        }

        #endregion
```

Now my Xaml

```
  <xctk:CheckListBox Height="200" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ActiveStudents, Mode=TwoWay}"
    Name="ActiveStudents" 
    DisplayMemberPath="Student"
    ValueMemberPath="StudentID" 
    SelectedMemberPath="Select"    
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStudent}"
    SelectedItemsOverride="{Binding SelectedStudentValue}"/>

<DataGrid  MaxHeight="200" MinHeight="200" Name="MyGrid"
        Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        HeadersVisibility="Column"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        AlternatingRowBackground="#F0EDF2"                                                             
        ItemsSource="{Binding GridDisplay}"   
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
        CanUserAddRows="false">
    <DataGrid.GroupStyle>.....
```

On top of all this I have a dropdown list that decides what students are pre checked in the checklistbox thus making them show up in the data grid. This last part I am sure I can figure out but I just cant get the students I select from the check list box to show in the data grid.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 1. If you post your code, post the private variables as well (so if someone tries to paste it and see if it works, he wouldn't need to add the private fields for all your student properties). 2. I'll take it you're using the CheckedListbox from the [wpf toolkit](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CheckListBox) ? If yes, which version?

Comment: It is the one from the wpf tool kit. I believe it is xceed or something. It is version 2. I have posted the private variables.

Answer (score 0):

CheckedListBox has an ItemCheck event.  You look at which item is checked/unchecked from within the event by e.Index.  You will also want to look at e.CurrentValue and e.NewValue.

Comment: CheckListBox doesn't seem to have an ItemCheck event. Closest I can find is ItemSelectionChanged event. It has RoutedEventArgs so there is no e.CurrentValue or e.NewValue.